# Inner for loop is not executed in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have inputs.csv like below

```
apple 400  
banana 401  
mango 430  
orange 440  
banana 401  
orange 440  
mango 430  
apple 400  
orange 440  
banana 401
```

i want my output like output.csv

```
apple 400  2  
banana 401 3  
mango 430 2   
orange 440 3
```

i.e we should count the number of items of that particular type and insert the count as the 3rd column

i have tried with the below code

```
with open('new.csv','r') as csvinput:
  with open('update.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.append("No.of.Rows")
    all.append(row)

    cn = Counter(map(itemgetter(0), reader))
    for k, v in cn.items():
        print("k compared is::",k)
        for row in reader:
           print("Executing inner loop")
           print("row value compared is ::",row[0])
           if k == row[0] :
             print("matched")
             # here i want to write the count v to the 3rd column
```

in my above code inner for loop is not getting executed.

can u please help me further

Comment: `map(itemgetter(0), reader)` consumed all the data in `reader`, so there was nothing left for the inner loop to do.

Comment: Thanks for the input , i modified the code like below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input , i modified the code like below

```
for k, v in cn.items():
         print("k compared is::",k)
         with open('new.csv','r') as csvinput:
              reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
              for row in reader:
                  print("Executing inner loop")
                  print("row value compared is ::",row[0])
                  if k == row[0] :
                     print("matched")
                     row.append(v)
                     all.append(row)
                     break
writer.writerows(all)
```

with this code it worked but my worry is csv file will be opened and read for k number of times , so is there any better solution

Comment: Don't worry about it until it becomes a problem, but you'll likely want to print less to improve performance

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will work

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
with open('new.csv','r') as csvinput:
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
    cn = Counter()
    for row in reader:
        trow=tuple(row)
        cn[trow] += 1
    print cn
with open('update.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
    for row in cn:
        writer.writerow([row[0],row[1],cn[row]])
```