# Count Identical items in csv and append the count as column

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i have inputs.csv like below

apple 400
banana 401
mango 430
orange 440
banana 401
orange 440
mango 430
apple 400
orange 440
banana 401

i want my output like output.csv

apple 400  2
banana 401 3
mango 430 2
orange 440 3

i.e we should count the number of items of that particular type and insert the count as the 3rd column

i have tried with the below code

```
with open('new.csv','r') as csvinput:
  with open('update.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.append("No.of.Rows")
    all.append(row)

    cn = Counter(map(itemgetter(0), reader))

    for k, v in cn.items():
         print("k compared is::",k)
         with open('new.csv','r') as csvinput:
              reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
              for row in reader:
                  print("Executing inner loop")
                  print("row value compared is ::",row[0])
                  if k == row[0] :
                     print("matched")
                     row.append(v)
                     all.append(row)
                     break
    writer.writerows(all)
```

with this code it worked but my worry is new.csv file will be opened and read for k number of times , so is there any better solution than this

Comment: Isn't this the same script as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312674/inner-for-loop-is-not-executed-in-python

Comment: I don't know what your code is trying to do, but make a dictionary with a key `(row[0], row[1])`, and the value being the sum of `row[2]` and you can do everything in one pass.

Comment: Read the file one into a list with `csvinput.readlines()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner for loop is not executed in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312674/inner-for-loop-is-not-executed-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) , you can load `csv` into a data-frame and manipulate easily and with three lines of code as below.

See pandas documentation for details.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=' ', header=None)
df.groupby([0,1]).size().to_csv('output.csv')
```

Once file is loaded directly to a data-frame df, it lists data as below

```
>>> df
        0    1
0   apple  400
1  banana  401
2   mango  430
3  orange  440
4  banana  401
5  orange  440
6   mango  430
7   apple  400
8  orange  440
9  banana  401
```

After grouping by columns and counting gives desired calculations in one line.

```
>>> df.groupby([0,1]).size()
0       1  
apple   400    2
banana  401    3
mango   430    2
orange  440    3
dtype: int64
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your approach to this:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('inputs.csv') as in_file, open('outputs.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    counts = Counter(map(str.strip, in_file))

    for k, v in sorted(counts.items()):
        out_file.write(k + ' ' + str(v) + '\n')
```

As shown, you only need to call `open()` when reading a file and writing to a file. If you want to read a file once, call `open()` once. I'm not sure why you would want to read it more times. This applies for writing to a file also.

Then if you want to view the contents of `outputs.csv` once, you can call this outside the `with` statement:

```
print(open('outputs.csv').read())
```

Which Outputs:

```
apple 400 2
banana 401 3
mango 430 2
orange 440 3
```

**Note:** Your files in the question are not `.csv` files, since they are not comma delimited. Having them as `.txt` files would be fine here.